# Android&SQLite: Стоит ли создавать несколько БД при большом количестве разнородных данных?

Tags: android, sqlite

Допустим, у нас есть приложение, которое может содержать большое количество неоднородных данных (текстовые записи, рисования на экране, списки, фото и т. д.). Однако, мы конечно не будем выгружать сразу все данные, а только те, которые нужны на данный момент.

Стоит ли в таком случае стремиться запихнуть все данные в одну БД с большим количеством таблиц, или же разумно сделать несколько БД и меньшим количеством таблиц?

Comment: О чем идет речь большое количество это что ??

Comment: сколько 10 тысяч строк столбцов о чем речь?

Comment: Сделайте так как вам удобно нет никаких правил но чтоб не запутаться лучше используйте удаленную бд  типо Mysql и в ней у вс будет фон через php myadmin легче будет управлять

Comment: "Большое количество" в данном вопросе означает большое разнообразие типов данных, не позволяющих хранить их в одной траблице.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд стоит все хранить в одной БД. Но я видел что иногда люди делают две БД. Есть у такого подхода и плюсы и минусы.

Минусы:

- Нужно хранить два singleton, которые будут работать со своими SQLiteOpenHelper.
- Если вам понадобиться связать данные из разных БД, то нужно будет делать как минимум два запроса к разным БД.

Плюсы:

- Иногда возникает такая ошибка database is locked. И если вы пишете из двух потоков разных соединений, то произойдет ошибка – ваши данные не запишутся в базу, а приложение вылетит с SQLiteDatabaseLockedException.
  Я видел, как с помощью двух БД решают эти проблемы.

Но на мой вариант этот плюс сомнительный.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Первый минус, конечно, существенный.

Comment: Ну это да. Но мне кажется просто не логично для одного приложения делать разные бд. У меня есть библиотека, для отображения БД, и писали о том чтобы я сделал отображения нескольких баз данных. https://github.com/pavel163/ProbeTools